# MultiValue Selection with MultiValue Input

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox, field-mapping, multi-values

I made this Python Toolbox as a practice run for a larger project I want to do as I am new to python toolboxes. While this was successful I am not able to the result that I want.

I want to be able to have multiple feature classes as inputs and then allow the users the chance to pick fields they would like to keep from all inputs. Either in check boxes or a drop down list. Much like when you have one input and then you can pick fields using the drop down menu.

I've explored the Field Map datatype to get the desired result but so far unsuccessful.

[image: input with drop down multivalue pick list]

```
import arcpy

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Deleting Fields as selected from drop down list"""
        self.label = "Delete Toolbox"
        self.alias = ""

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [DeleteField]


class DeleteField(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Delete fields from check list"""
        self.label = "Delete Fields"
        self.description = "Delete fields"
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""

        InputTable= arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName= "Input Table",
            name="InputTable",
            datatype= ["DEFeatureDataset", "DETable"],
            parameterType= "Required",
            direction= "Input",
            multiValue=False)

        Fields = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Fields to delete",
            name="DeleteFields",
            datatype=["Field"],
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input",
            multiValue=True)

        Fields.parameterDependencies= [InputTable.name]

        parameters=[InputTable,Fields]

        return parameters

    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
        has been changed."""
        return

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
        return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""

        InputTable  = parameters[0].valueAsText
        DeleteFields   = parameters[1].valueAsText


        des=arcpy.Describe(InputTable)
        fieldlist=des.fields
        DeleteList=[]

        for field in fieldlist:
            if not field.required:
                if field.name in DeleteFields:
                    DeleteList.append(field.name)
        for f in DeleteList:
            arcpy.DeleteField_management(InputTable,f)
            return InputTable
```

Comment: feature class schema is the same for all fcs?

Comment: No, different for each. That is why I want the user to be able to select different fields for each FC.

Comment: You want to iterate over all fcs at once or one fc at once?

Comment: I'd like the user to be able to select multiple fcs and multiple fields from each fc and then it would run through the script one at a time I guess.

Comment: In python toolbox logic I dont know if this is possible. I can write that will show you a list of all fcs (but all fcs must have same scheme) or you pick one fc and you will recieve all fields. In command line python script it can be possibly done but it will be user unfriendly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will help you a bit.

With this tool you select gdb.
It will give you list of fcs inside of it.
Then when you pick one or more  you will get list of fields. (result is always from  the fc in 1st place)

```
import arcpy

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Deleting Fields as selected from drop down list"""
        self.label = "Delete Toolbox"
        self.alias = ""

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [DeleteField]


class DeleteField(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Delete fields from check list"""
        self.label = "Delete Fields"
        self.description = "Delete fields"
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""

        in_gdb = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = "Pick source gdb",
            name = "in_gdb",
            datatype = "DEWorkspace",
            parameterType = "Required",
            direction = "Input",
            multiValue = False)


        fcs = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = "Feature Classes",
            name = "fcs_gdb",
            datatype = "GPString",
            parameterType = "Required",
            direction = "Input",
            multiValue = True)

        fcs.filter.type = "ValueList"  

        fields_fc = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = "Fields",
            name = "fields_of_fc",
            datatype = "GPString",
            parameterType = "Required",
            direction = "Input",
            multiValue = True)

        fields_fc.filter.type = "ValueList"  



        parameters=[in_gdb ,fcs, fields_fc]

        return parameters

    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
        has been changed."""

        if parameters[0].value:
            arcpy.env.workspace = parameters[0].value
            fc_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

            parameters[1].filter.list = fc_list

        if parameters[1].value:
            fcs = [parameters[1].value.exportToString()]

            temp_list = arcpy.ListFields(fcs[0])

            final_list= [f.name for f in temp_list]
            parameters[2].filter.list = final_list





        return

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
        return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
```

Comment: Thank you, no way to make the list be a Table.FieldName situation?

Comment: Im gonna dive into it, this evening - later tomorrow